# Extending the stay in the US On the VWP once in the country

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-free-entry

I m travelling to the US in June on the VWP and have a return flight 10 days later but I may want to extend this but still well within the 90 day limit. what are the implications on re entering later in the year if I actually extend once im over there ??

Comment: Just so I'm sure: You intend to travel to the US, with a return ticket for 10 days later - however, some circumstances may see you remaining longer. You also intend to make subsequent visits this year to the US. You wish to know if telling the CBP officer at the border ("I'm leaving in 10 days") and then leaving at some point later will cause any sanctions against you? Where will you be returning to?

Comment: There are none. Normally, you are admitted for 90 days even if you ask only for 10 days). After that, you can indeed stay for 90 days, and there is nothing wrong with that. When re-entering later in the year, it must be clear to the immigration officer must however not have the impression that you are actually trying to move to the US. If you don't overdo it and have documentation that both of your stays are within the rules of the VWP, then you *should* normally be fine.

Comment: @DCTLib Why is that a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Cmaster Because there was recently this discussion whether one is always admitted for 90 days under US VWP or not on this site. Most answers state that this doesn't need to be the case, but someone digged out an immigration officer manual that it should be the case. The completeness of the answer somewhat depends on whether this is the case or not.

Comment: Why not simply tell it as it is to the officer at the border when he asks when you're going to leave? "I'm booked to go back Thursday next week, but it's possible I'll have to stay on a few weeks beyond that if problems develop". It is routine for VWP travelers to be granted 90 days even through their booked return flight is only a few days after they enter, so your only worry ought to be not to actively _lie_ about your intentions.

Comment: See alsp: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66243/what-is-the-us-visa-waiver-program-and-what-is-an-esta

Comment: @DCTLib: I think that was me :) I commented somewhere that in the copy of the CBP Inspector's Field Manual that was released publicly, it said something like VWP will always be admitted for 90 days unless the passport has a shorter expiration. However, that only reflects the policy from the time of the version of the manual that was released, many years ago, and also the CBP doesn't use the IFM anymore, and what they do use now has never been released. So take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Travel plans are subject to change, and the CBP know this. [Indeed one can even apply for an ESTA with provisional, if not indefinite, plans.](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1098/~/esta---applying-for-esta-if-travel-plans-are-indefinite) If admitted for entry in the US under the Visa Waiver Program, you'll be authorised to stay for a maximum of 90 days. The important thing is not overstaying, rather than extending a provisional travel plan.

When the immigration officer asks you about your plans **be honest** and you should be fine. Mention that you thought of staying X days when you applied for the ESTA, but are now thinking of staying more than that for whatever reason. As long as the reason is valid for admission under the VWP you should have no problems. Should you be question upon re-visiting the US, the advice is always the same: be honest.

For more information on the VWP and ESTA, see [our canonical question on the topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66243/what-is-the-us-visa-waiver-program-and-what-is-an-esta).

Comment: Is one even asked about length of stay **when applying for an ESTA**? I don't remember answering such a question the times I've needed one, (but it is difficult to get to see the non-first pages of the questionnaire without actually starting an application -- which I'm wary of doing on false pretenses just out of curiosity).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Maybe not the length of stay but the travel details for sure. Although one can say "unknown".