# Can a US Citizen work whilst travelling in UK?

Tags: uk, legal, us-citizens, work, standard-visitor-visas

I know that a US citizen could potentially remain in the UK for up to 6 months on travel. However, I'm also sure that this wouldn't allow them to work while here. If someone were to be visiting the UK for this long, are there legal ways to earn an income while in the UK for 6 months of travel?

Comment: What does acceptable mean? Legal? In terms of standards of living?

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear - I mean legal. Edited the post.

Comment: Legally? Don't use the 6 month visa-free entry, but apply for the correct type of work visa (which may or may not also allow longer than 6 months). Alternativley, have sufficent investments that they pay an income that can sustain you.

Comment: Is this a digital nomad type of enquiry? Or more towards what's legal, like dividends, rental income, and such? Unclear.

Comment: Put I'm simply, I'm looking for what options are available for a US national to support themselves while in the UK for a period of up to 6 months.

Comment: You'd need to get a work permit rather than enter as a "visitor."

Comment: @millerbr, the options are T2, T5.

Comment: the simple answer is "of course not, obviously not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Working on a Standard Visitor Visa

[You can't do paid nor unpaid work on a UK Standard Visitor visa.](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview)

> You can’t:
>
> - do paid or unpaid work
> - live in the UK for long periods of time through frequent visits
> - get public funds
> - marry or register a civil partnership, or give notice of marriage or civil partnership

Similarly, [you can't do paid nor unpaid work if entering the UK as a visa exempt US citizen (or any other non-visa national)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66243/what-is-the-us-visa-waiver-program-and-what-is-an-esta).

### Working in the UK

To work in the UK you'll have to apply for [the appropriate Work Visa](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas). [There are some exceptions to this for US citizens coming into the UK for less than 6 months with the purpose of working](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/work/six_months_or_less), provided:

> You don’t need a visa if you’re coming to the UK for activities allowed under the following visas:
>
> - a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) - eg if you’re coming to the UK for conferences, meetings, training, academic research or a sabbatical
> - a [‘permitted paid engagement’](https://www.gov.uk/permitted-paid-engagement-visa) (you must have been invited to the UK because of your expertise) - you can only stay for up to 1 month
>
> However, you should bring [supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) to show at the border.

Comment: (Or the visa exemption that US citizens enter on)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that all of the available work visas for a US citizen would only be accessible if you have a company willing to sponsor you?

Comment: @millerbr Have a read: https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas

Comment: Yep been reading through that - looks like the best way is to get a company to sponsor you. I might be stretching now, but do you know of any options available to someone who doesn't have a degree?

Comment: @millerbr For extended discussion use [the travel chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your nationality you can [apply for a Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility/overview):

- want to live and work in the UK for up to 2 years
- are aged 18 to 30
- have £1,890 in savings
- have certain types of British Nationality or are from certain countries
- meet the other eligibility requirements

Currently allowed nationalities:-

- Australia
- Canada
- Japan
- Monaco
- New Zealand
- Hong Kong
- Republic of Korea
- Taiwan

I have copied only some portions from the website. For full details do visit the website as that will be the most authentic source of information.

Comment: Reading through this, it would seem this doesn't apply to someone who was born in the US?

Comment: Americans do not qualify for YMS, the US govt turned it down.

Comment: @GayotFow I presume because the UK expects reciprocal "Working Holiday Visa" opportunity for Britons?

Comment: @CMaster, yes reciprocity has to be part of the deal and they were not buying into it. I'll let you figure out why :)

Comment: Of course, young brits have the opportunity to work on US Summer Camps (I don't know what visa/permit they use). I can't think of a similar line of work for the UK.

Comment: @CMaster  BUNAC, different can of worms

Comment: @millerbr to be precise, the place of birth is irrelevant.  The country of citizenship controls.  It's possible for a person to be born in the US to hold other nationalities besides US (and in rare circumstances it's even possible for someone born in the US not to be a US citizen, namely the child of parents with diplomatic immunity).

Comment: @CMaster That would be the J-1 exchange visitor visa.  See https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/exchange.html.  This requires a sponsor, which I don't think the Working Holiday Visa requires.