# Does visiting Canada from USA under ESTA reset the visa waiver?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm staying in the US under the Visa Waiver Program at the moment, until 8th March. I'm planning to visit Montreal, Canada, for a week and then come back to the States.

Is a new visa waiver required to come back to the States or is the old one still valid after leaving the country?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/visiting-the-us-twice-under-one-esta?rq=1

Comment: @pnuts the expiration of the ESTA authorization is not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 8):

If you enter the US under Visa Waiver, then exit to Canada and reenter the US you do not need a new Visa Waiver. More importantly, for calculating the maximum length of stay in the US you are **treated as not having left the US** for the time you were in Canada. You will need to leave 90 days after the first day you arrived.

Answer (score 1):

Your ESTA is valid for 2 years, provided your passport doesn't expire sooner.

If you return to the US before your original 90-day period expires (i.e. before the handwritten date on your US entry stamp) then you won't need an I-94W. Otherwise, you will need it, but with a valid ESTA they'll print a pre-filled form rather than you having to fill it out manually.

Answer (score -3):

Going to Canada is not supposed to reset the 90 days on the ESTA. **However**, in my case my (pedestrian) exit at Rainbow Bridge was recorded as a full exit, and at Toronto preclearance, getting back into the USA (by flying to Chicago), I did get a full new 90 days. This did confuse the official but the computer had already approved it so that's what I got.

Comment: Hi Simon - this doesn't answer the question, as it was obviously a mistake, rather than policy

Comment: @RoryAlsop it's not obviously a mistake.  The policy allows discretion on the part of the border officer to grant a new 90-day period of admission; that could be what happened here.