# ESTA USA validity

Tags: usa, esta, visa-expiration

I have a valid ESTA for the USA until November 24, 2023.
I should travel next October, so the ESTA will have expired when I will be in the US territory.
Can I travel without problems or is it advisable to renew?
Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me with the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ESTA has to be valid at the moment of entry in the US. It does not need to be valid for the entire duration of stay in the US. Therefore, there is no need to apply for a new ESTA if your existing one expires while you are visiting the US

[What is the US Visa Waiver Program and what is an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66243/what-is-the-us-visa-waiver-program-and-what-is-an-esta)